# special polynomial

Tags: galois-theory

Is there a polynomial with coefficients -1,0,1 which is irreducible over the
 rationals and has the alternating group as its galois group ?

More concrete : Is there a polynomial of degree n, all coefficients -1,0 or 1,
 irreducible over the rationals with galois group A(n) ?

For small degrees, I enumerated the polynomials and none had the property.
 So I am curious if there are really none.

Comment: It may take a while to fond one. Think of the almost, but not totally unrelated fact the the cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_n$ have coefficients in $\{-1,0,1\}$ until you check $n=105$.

Comment: There might be some clues in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286944/quintic-polynomial-with-galois-group-a-5

Comment: I checked the polynomials up to degree 8 and there is none.

Answer (score 0):

x^9 - x^8 - x^7 - x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x - 1

is a polynomial with Galois-Group A(9)

as I calculated with MAGMA online.

Comment: Hi Peter, it looks like you have multiple accounts on this website. I would suggest registering one of your accounts and follow the steps described [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge) to consolidate your various accounts.

Comment: would you mind giving some explanation of how you derived this?