# Is there always a prime having only one prime above it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, prime-factorization

Given a number field $K / \Bbb Q$, can we find a prime $p \in \Bbb Z$ which has only one prime of $K$ above it (e.g. $p$ is inert or $p$ is totally ramified)?

For instance, if $K$ is Galois over $\Bbb Q$ with non-cyclic Galois group, then no prime of $\Bbb Q$ is inert in $K$. But maybe we could have totally ramified primes, or a factorization like $p O_K = P^s$ with $1 \leq s \leq [K:\Bbb Q]$. (What happens if we assume $K/\Bbb Q$ to be Galois ?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the cyclotomic field $K=\Bbb Q(\zeta_8)$ $\mathcal O_K = \Bbb Z[\zeta_8]$, this has a non-cyclic Galois group, so no prime is inert in $K$. The only prime that is ramified in $K$ is $2$, but $2$ is totally ramified, so this is not a counterexample yet.

Now consider $L=\Bbb Q(\zeta_7)$, where $7$ is the only ramified prime and there are two different primes above $(2)$ and conversely, there are two distinct primes above $(7)$ in $K$. (This is becaue the $8$th cyclotomic polynomial $x^4+1$ splits as $x^4+1=(x^2+3x+1)(x^2+4x+1) \pmod{7}$ and the $7$th cyclotomic polynomial $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^3+x^2+x+1$ splits as $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=(x^3+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1) \pmod{2}$)

So if we take the composite field $K \cdot L = \Bbb Q(\zeta_{56})$, we get an extension such that there are at least two primes above every prime in $\Bbb Z$. $K \cdot L$ is also Galois.

Comment: Thank you very much. Why are there two distinct primes of $L$ above $2\Bbb Z$, and why are there two distinct primes of $K$ above $7\Bbb Z$ ?

Comment: Very nice answer :-)

Comment: @Alphonse I have edited in a justifaction based on the factorization of cyclotomic polynomials over the residue fields. That's rather ad hoc, though, the splitting and ramification behaviour of rational primes in cyclotomic fields is very well understood. You can reduce this to computing the order of $2$ in $(\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z)^\times$ and the order of $7$ in $(\Bbb Z/8 \Bbb Z)^\times$ All texts on algebraic number theory should have some material on that, I suggest you check that out.

Answer (score 3):

If there is only one prime of $K$ above $p$, then $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)$ is isomorphic to the decomposition group of $p$. But the decomposition group is solvable (the higher ramification groups are a composition series).

In particular, any extension with non-solvable Galois group will work.

Comment: Don't you need rather that the _decomposition group_ of $p$ is solvable (which is the whole Galois group exactly when $p$ has only one prime above it) ?

Comment: The smallest non-solvable group is $A_5$, so [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286944/) provides an example.

Comment: (With your answer dealing only with the inertia group, I only see that there is no _totally ramified_ prime, but not that there is no prime having only one prime above it).

Comment: You're right. In my head, I was only answering the totally ramified part, because you answered the inert part in the question. Of course any non-solvable group is also non-cyclic, so my original answer was still valid.

Comment: The point of this answer is that if you choose a 'typical' polynomial of degree $\ge 5$, then its splitting field will give you an example. Of course, as the other answer shows, there are examples even with $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)$ abelian.