# How to get a specific polynomial with a unsolvable Galois group?

Tags: galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

As the *Galois theory*, **all solution** of a polynomial with a solvable Galois group cannot be expressed by form of radicals. This mean, even for unsolvable polynomials, it is possible that **some of the solutions** can be written in the form of radicals. Can we find one such unsolvable polynomial? Which is its root solution.

Comment: Examples can be found in [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286944/quintic-polynomial-with-galois-group-a-5?rq=1) (which appeared in the links on the right side of the page for this question).

Comment: For irreducible polynomials, all roots are conjugate under Galois so one of the roots can be expressed with radicals iff every root can.

Comment: @GregMartin I realize that your comments are contradictory to Aphell's. and did not find the corresponding polynomial in your link

Comment: Greg Martin's comment is about the question in the title, only meant to address the requirement of an unsolvable Galois group. If you want a polynomial with an unsolvable Galois group with some roots still in terms of radicals, you must use a reducible polynomial like
$$(x^2-2)(x^5+2x+1).$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen What you gave is indeed a reducible polynomial, a reducible polynomial is not possible to satisfy my requirement, right? Do you have any basis (theorem)?

Comment: What Aphelli said. If $f(x)$ is irreducible over some field $K$ and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two of its roots, then $K(\alpha)$ and $K(\beta)$ are $K$-isomorphic as fields. This measns that if one is a root tower extension so is the other.

Comment: The general philosophy here is that it is impossible to distinguish between two roots of an irreducible polynomial by algebraic means alone.

Comment: @Aphelli Is [this quote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ3Vq.png) from the book(*Visual Group Theory*) your theoretical basis for your this comment [above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472195/how-to-get-a-specific-polynomial-with-a-unsolvable-galois-group#comment9374072_4472195)? But it does not seem to state that **"one of the roots can be expressed with radicals iff every root can"**. I would very much like to understand this statement of yours. Can you elaborate on it?

Comment: Yes, that quote is what I meant by “all roots are conjugate under Galois”. To conclude, one simply needs to see that if $z$ can be expressed by radicals, any conjugate of $z$ can.

Comment: @Aphelli I can't find out the source of your [this statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472195/how-to-get-a-specific-polynomial-with-a-unsolvable-galois-group?noredirect=1#comment9424666_4472195:~:text=I%20meant%20by%20%E2%80%9C-,all%20roots%20are%20conjugate%20under%20Galois,-%E2%80%9D.%20To%20conclude%2C%20one). Is this your own understanding, or is it some conclusion in mathematics?

Comment: An algebraic number $z$ is solvable by radicals if there exists a cyclotomic extension $K_0/\mathbb{Q}$ and a sequence of fields $K_0 \subset K_1 \ldots \subset K_n$ with $z \in K_n$, and $K_i=K_{i-1}(u_i^{1/m_i})$ where $K_0$ contains the $m_i$-th roots of unity and $u_i \in K_{i-1}$. With this definition, it’s clear that the Galois conjugate of an algebraic number solvable by radicals remains solvable by radicals.