# If there is a Galois extension with degree $[E:F] = n$, is there necessarily some subfield $K$ such that $[K:F] = m$ where $m \mid n$?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

For example, consider $[E:F] = 1368$. Since $1368$ is divisible by $36$, is there necessarily some subextension $K/F$ such that $[K:F] = 36$, or is it just possible for one to exist? I have been self-studying abstract algebra for a few months and for some reason, field theory has been incredibly difficult for me to grasp. Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: If $E/F$ is Galois, then the intermediate fields are in $1$-$1$ correspondence with the subgroups of the Galois group.  So the answer to your question depends on whether the Galois group of $E/F$ has a subgroup of index $36$.

Comment: A polynomial with [Galois group $A_5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286944/quintic-polynomial-with-galois-group-a-5). So $[E:F]=60$. Could there be a $K$ with $[K:F]=30$?

Comment: Why wouldn't there be such a field $K$ @2'59'2 ? Surely $A_5$ has an element $\sigma$ of order two, when the field of the fixed points $\sigma$ is a degree $30$ extension of $F$. On the other hand, if the Galois group of the Galois extension $E/F$ is $\simeq A_5$ then there aren't any intermediate fields  $K$ such that $[K:F]=2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Mixed up, sorry. Change my $[K:F]$ to $[E:K]$ then.

Comment: No problem @2'59'2 . Trust me, all learners of Galois theory make that particular mistake a handful of times. Particularly because in the first examples the Galois group is always the Klein four, and consequently the index and the order are equal for each and every non-trivial subgroup!