# Does a simple group of order 60 has a cyclic subgroup of order 6

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I was unable to solve the following question in abstract algebra quiz, so I am posting it here.

> Let G be a simple group  of order 60. Then prove that it doesn't have a cyclic subgroup of order 6.

Using sylow theorems and that group is simple , I got No. of sylow 5 subgroups are 6 and number of Sylow 3 subgroup are 4 or 10 and number if sylow 2 subgroups are 15 or 3 or 5.

But I noticed that in any combinations sum of elements in not 60.

Can you please tell what mistake I am making?

---

Another thought i had was that by cauchy theorem there exists an element og=f both 2 and 3 so they will generate a subgroup of order 2 and 3 respectively say A and B . SO, why doesnot there exists a cyclic subgroup  of order 6 (A $\times$ B)?

Please illuminate on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any simple group of order $60$ must be isomorphic to $A_5$. [refer [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/A5_is_the_unique_simple_non-abelian_group_of_smallest_order#Proof_that_there_is_only_one_simple_group_of_order_sixty.2C_isomorphic_to_the_alternating_group_of_degree_five)]

Suppose $A_5$ has a cyclic subgroup of order $6$, this means that $A_5$ has an element of order $6$. But element of order $6$ in $S_5$ must be in the form $(ab)(cde)$ which is an odd permutation. Hence $A_5$ does not have any cyclic subgroup of order $6$.

Comment: I want to do it without knowing that it must be isomorphic to $A_5$ . Can you please help with that?

Answer (score 4):

A nonabelian simple group cannot contain a proper subgroup of index less than $5$. ($*$)

(See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134437), for example,  for a proof.)

So the number of Sylow $3$-subgroups cannot be $4$, and hence it must be $10$.

Let $P \in {\rm Syl}_3(G)$. Then $|N_G(P)| = 6$, and to prove that $G$ has no cyclic subgroup of order $6$, we need to prove that $N_G(P)$ is not cyclic.

So suppose it is, and let $g \in N_G(P)$ have order $2$. Let $H = C_G(g)$.
Since $g \in H$ and $H$must also contain a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$, we have $|H| \ge 12$, and then by $(*)$ we must have $|H| = 12$.

Since $N_G(P) \le H$, $H$ has at most two Sylow $3$-subgroups, and so by Sylow it has only one, but then $P \lhd H$, contradiction.

Comment: Can you please tell what's wrong with my 2nd expalnation which involves cauchy theorem on elements?

Comment: @Tim I don't understand what you are saying. Cauchy's theorem says that there are elements of orders $2$ and $3$, which is correct.But what has that got to do with elements of order $6$? Cauchy's theorem says nothing about that.

Comment: I found mistake in my argument.